# Pyomo CBC solver error: Solver (cbc) returned non-zero return code (3221225781); Solver (cbc) did not exit normally

Tags: python, optimization, solver, pyomo

I'm working on an optimization problem on PyCharm using the CBC solver and I keep having this error:

*ERROR: Solver (cbc) returned non-zero return code (3221225781)*

and

*pyutilib.common._exceptions.ApplicationError: Solver (cbc) did not exit normally*

I've added the "keepfiles=True" argument but I can't finde the solver log and solution file, although I can finde the problem files on the path the program returns.

It is worth nothing that this program runs properly on my colleague's computer, (he has 16Gb RAM and I have 8)

Comment: Try adding the option `tee=True`, this will print the solver output to the screen

Comment: I've already done that, still doesn't work:

opt.solve(model, tee=True, keepfiles=True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution by myself and I'll post it here in case is usefull for anyone in the future:

When installing a solver, you must add the solver.exe file into the system PATH or just place the file in the folder where the python file is placed

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem with the `ipopt` solver.
It was solved by adding the solver to the system `PATH`, but it only worked after restarting the computer!

Answer (score 1):

in addition to @Camunatas's solution (if that doesn't work) do add all the DLLs and exe's which are the package of COIN OR(blis,bonmin,cbc,clp,couenne,ipopt,OSSolverService,symphony) package in the same directory/folder where the python files are.as these exes are the only installers for windows and they should always be with their DLLs to work.